# combine fork execl wait

Tags: c, linux

I have to create prog1 which take one argument with number of children have to create. (example "./prog1 5" - will create 5 children) Each of children will generate random number from 1 to 20. This number will be given to execl which will start prog2 (in same folder) which take as a argument this random number. Prog2 should sleep this random number time. After that it should return this random number to parent.
I created something like this but it still don't work properly.

prog1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n, i, pid;
    int u = getppid();
    int procesy = 0;

    pid_t proc_id;

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        proc_id = fork();

        if(proc_id==0)
        {
            srand(getpid());
            u = 1 + rand()%20;
            execl("./prog2", "prog2", u,0);

        }
        else
        {
            procesy++;
        }
    }

    if(u == getppid())
    {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            pid = wait(&u);
            printf("Process %d ende\n", pid);
            procesy--;
        }

        if(procesy == 0) printf("endc\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

prog2:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int n;
      n = atoi(argv[1]);
      sleep(n);

      exit(n);
    }
```

Comment: 1) execl's varargs must be const char *'s, not ints; you pass in `u` which is an int. Convert it. 2) `if(u == getppid())` has no meaning in this program. It's code that is only executed by your primary program, which gets the process id of its parent (probably the shell you're using), which I'm pretty sure isn't your intention.

Comment: I added char dig = (char)(((int)'0')+n);
   execl("./prog2", "prog2", dig,0); and remove if(u==getppid()) program nothing do now

Comment: from docs : "The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL."
Replace that `0` with `(char *) NULL`

Comment: `char` is not the same as `char *`... but more precisely, the `char *` must be null terminated... each element is a NULL terminated c string exactly as if you were typing the command on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to look something like the following, in order to properly call execl():

```
if(proc_id==0)
{
    char arg[16];
    srand(getpid());
    sprintf(arg, "%d", 1 + rand()%20);
    execl("./prog2", "prog2", arg, 0);
    printf("I should not be here!\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Then get rid of `if(u == getppid())` (but keep the contents of the conditional). It seems with that `if` you were trying to filter out the child from running that block. When `execl()` works, the child is not going to run *anything* in this code after the `execl()`... the printf and exit I added will not be run. Those lines will only run if `execl()` fails, and in this simple case, the only way it will fail is if you've provided improper arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much :D you are my hero now I understand a lot of more